# Can the words "also" and "too" be used in the same sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, too-also

`also` and `too` -- can these two words be used in the same sentence? For example:

> I have **also** done this **too**.

The above sentence does not make sense to me though. But *Grammarly Premium* (an online-based grammar-checking service) did not catch any issue in the sentence. That is why I am confused about whether the sentence is actually correct or not.

Comment: This sentence is grammatically correct (that is, all parts of speech are in the right places, verb tenses are correct, etc.), but it is stylistically bad and most people would find the redundancy unacceptable. It's possible for a sentence to have correct *grammar* while still being unacceptable for other reasons.

Comment: @CanadianYankee: You may post your comment as an answer since it has answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence is grammatically correct (that is, all parts of speech are in the right places, verb tense and number are correct, etc.), but it stylistically bad and most native speakers would find the redundancy unacceptable.

It is possible for a sentence to have correct grammar while still being unacceptable for other reasons.

Some automated grammar checkers may have other sorts of checks (e.g., for redundancy) built into them, but no automated tool - even a premium one - is going to be perfect.